# equality of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

For $z\in { C }, \Re (z)\neq 2$ we have $F(z)=\frac { 4-z\overline { z }  }{ 4-z-\overline { z }  }$.
I'm trying to prove the equality between the modulus of these numbers without using the exponential form, so how can I prove that?

$$|F(z)-z|=|F(z)-2|$$

Comment: Hint: $|w|^2=w\bar w$ for a complex number $w$.

Comment: I don't think would help.

Comment: Nothing else matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a simple calculation, we have:
$$
|F(z) - z| = \left|\frac{(z-2)^2}{\overline{z}+z-4}\right|
$$

And:
$$
|F(z) - 2| = \left|\frac{(z-2) \left(\overline{z}-2\right)}{\overline{z}+z-4}\right|
$$

But:
$$
|\overline{z} - 2| = |\overline{z-2}| = |z-2|
$$

Plug in and the desired result will immediately follow.

Answer (score 2):

$$|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$$

$$\begin{align*}
|F(z)-z|^2 &= (F(z)-z)(\bar{F(z)}-\bar{z})\\
&= |F(z)|^2-z\bar{F(z)}-\bar{z}F(z)+|z|^2
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
|F(z)-2|^2 &= (F(z)-2)(\bar{F(z)}-2)\\
&= |F(z)|^2-2\bar{F(z)}-2F(z)+|2|^2
\end{align*}$$

Set them equal, the $|F(z)|^2$ terms cancel, from here it should be simple algebra.

Also, note that $\Re(z) = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$.

This means $2(F(z)+\bar{F(z)}) = 4\Re(F(z))$.